# How to tell google chrome to respect system default file browser (Thunar) on Xfce?

Tags: google-chrome, nautilus, thunar

In Chrome, after downloading a file, clicking on the "Show in folder" menu now force to use nautilus to open the folder, but my system preferred file browser is Thunar on my xfce desktop.

is there a way to let chrome to open folder using system preferred file browser?

system is Ubuntu 16.04, xfce 4.12

[image: see settings]

Answer (score -2):

I found out that the "Show in folder" option in Chrome triggers a hard coded execution of Dolphin. As a matter of fact in Google "help" it is said you cannot change this setting... well Linux is free as in I decide how my system works... thus, I did a quick and dirty hack:

```
    sudo apt remove dolphin
    sudo ln /usr/bin/thunar /usr/bin/dolphin
```

I know this could be improved a lot, but for now I am getting Thunar instead of Dolphin as I wanted. Hope this works for you.